# Getting undefined at node when i am selecting it by req.body.status

Tags: node.js, select, drop-down-menu

here is my code for select in html

```
<select class="status" name="status">
        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
        <option value="Done">Done</option>
</select>
```

here is my code for server.js

```
App.post('/userAddedIntoTable',(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body.status);
res.send("testing");
```

});

Comment: Hi there, can you post the full `<form>` code and how you're submitting the data to the Backend with the http request as well. You might also need to show how your NodeJS Backend code looks like with all its settings and configs.

Comment: Please post your complete snippet.